# how to modify struct fields in golang

Tags: go, struct

I have example [play.golang.org/p/Y1KX-t5Sj9](https://play.golang.org/p/Y1KX-t5Sj9) where I define method Modify() on struct User

```
type User struct {
  Name string
  Age int
}
func (u *User) Modify() {
  *u = User{Name: "Paul"}
}
```

in the main() I am defining struct literal **&User{Name: "Leto", Age: 11}** then call **u.Modify()**. That results in printing '**Paul 0**' I like that struct *field Name* is changed , but what is the correct way to keep *Age field* ?

Comment: I wish someone could explain the downvotes. This looks like a perfect question: OP gives a code example, explains what they're trying to do, then asks for help on how to solve their problem.

Comment: I agree with you. It's a good question for newbie of Golang.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just modify the field you want to change:

```
func (u *User) Modify() {
  u.Name = "Paul"
}
```

This is covered well in [the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/3) which you should definitely read through, it doesn't take long.

Comment: Just as a comment to help others if needed - make sure that your signature definition is a pointer: `func (u *User) Modify()`, not simply as a value: `func (u User) Modify()` - This caught me out.

Comment: @rhughes thanks for this, would be really nice to know mechanics behind this. If it is not defined as a struct, does it mean the operation will be performed against a new (blank, zero) struct?

Comment: @KirillG. This may answer your question: https://tour.golang.org/methods/4